# Graph papers black in python GUI

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I try to make a line graph in tkinter using the data in the database but then the graph appears as black only in the GUI.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

###------Show Information Using Graph-------###

graquery = '''SELECT Date, Amount FROM balance'''
CURSOR.execute(graquery)
graresults = CURSOR.fetchall()
Date = [result[0] for result in graresults]
Amount = [result[1] for result in graresults]
figure = plt.figure()
plt.plot(Date, Amount)
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Amount')
plt.title('Balance graph Graph')
gracanvas = Canvas(main_WINDOW, width=1070, height=452)
gracanvas.pack()
gracanvas.place(x=356, y=270)
figure_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, canvas)
figure_canvas.draw()
```

Answer (score 0):

change:

```py
figure_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, canvas)
```

to the following:

```py
figure_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, gracanvas)
```

Also change this:

```py
figure_canvas.draw()
```

to this:

```py
gracanvas.create_window(0, 0, window=figure_canvas.get_tk_widget())
```

It appears that you are attempting to show a graph created using matplotlib within a tkinter interface. The cause of the black graph could be due to a few factors.

It is necessary to confirm that the appropriate backend is being utilized to display the graph in tkinter. In the code provided, you have imported the correct backend, FigureCanvasTkAgg, which is used for displaying matplotlib graphs in tkinter.

It is important to ensure that the figure_canvas object is placed in the correct tkinter widget. In the code provided, you have created a Canvas widget and are attempting to display the figure_canvas object within it, but it seems that you are using the variable canvas instead of gracanvas. It is suggested to use gracanvas instead of canvas.

Lastly, in order to show the graph in your GUI, you should call the get_tk_widget() method on the figure_canvas object to obtain the tkinter widget that can be displayed.